# bash array leave elements containing string

Tags: arrays, bash, element, conditional-statements

I will be short, what i have is

```
array=( one.a two.b tree.c four.b five_b_abc)
```

I want this

```
array=( two.b four.b five_b_abc )
```

from [here](http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/1826)  i found this

```
# replace any array item matching "b*" with "foo"
array=( foo bar baz )
array=( "${array[@]/%b*/foo}" )
echo "${orig[@]}"$'\n'"${array[@]}"
```

how ever this does not work

```
array2=( ${array[@]//%^.p/})
```

result `array2=array`

this deletes all with p

```
array2=(${array[@]/*p*/})
```

result `array2=( one.a  tree.c )`

I need an idea how to do add ^p (all accept p), and get my solution

```
array2=(${array[@]/*^p*/}
```

Its a rather large array about 10k elements  where i need to do this i need it to be as fast as possible with data so please no loop solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: added timing comparisons (at end) and got rid of the `tr`

It is possible to *replace* the content of array elements using bash *[Parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)*, ie. `${var[@]....}` but you cannot actually *delete* the elements. The best you can get with parameter expansion is to make null ("") those elements you do not want.

Instead, you can use `printf` and `sed`, and `IFS`. This has the advantabe of allowing you to use full regular expression syntax (not just the shell globbing expressions)... and it is *much* faster than using a loop...

This example leaves array elements which contain `c`
**Note:** This method caters for spaces in data. This is achieved via `IFS=\n`

```
IFS=$'\n'; a=($(printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}" |sed '/c/!d'))
```

Here it is again with before/after dumps:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=(one.ac two.b tree.c four.b "five b abcdefg" )

echo "======== Original array ===="
printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}"

echo "======== Array containing only the matched elements 'c' ===="
IFS=$'\n'; a=($(printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}" |sed '/c/!d'))
printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}"
echo "========"
```

Output:

```
======== Original array ====
one.ac
two.b
tree.c
four.b
five b abcdefg
======== Array containing only the matched elements 'c' ====
one.ac
tree.c
five b abcdefg
========
```

---

For general reference: Testing an array containing 10k elements. selecting 5k:

```
a=( a\ \ \ \ b{0..9999} )
```

The printf method took: `0m0.226s` (results in sequential index values)
    The first loop method: `0m4.007s` (it leaves gaps in index values)
The second loop method: `0m7.862s` (results in sequential index values)

printf method:

```
IFS=$'\n'; a=($(printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}" |sed '/.*[5-9]...$/!d'))
```

1st loop method:

```
iz=${#a[@]}; j=0
for ((i=0; i<iz; i++)) ;do
    [[ ! "${a[i]}" =~ .*[5-9]...$ ]] && unset a[$i]
done
```

2nd loop method:

```
iz=${#a[@]}; j=0
for ((i=0; i<iz; i++)) ;do
    if [[ ! "${a[i]}" =~ .*[5-9]...$ ]] ;then
        unset a[$i]
    else 
        a[$j]="${a[i]}=$i=$j"; ((j!=i)) && unset a[$i]; ((j+=1)); 
    fi
done
```

Comment: I wish to give my thanks to you,too. site ypu added is in my bookmarks  from now on.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
array2=(`echo ${array[@]} | sed 's/ /\n/g' | grep b`)
```

Comment: both solutions are great, but i have used yours

Answer (score 0):

If you set IFS to $'\n', then you could use the **echo** command on the array with an '*' as the subscript, instead of printf with an '@':

```
IFS=$'\n'; a=($(echo "${a[*]}" | sed '/.*[5-9]...$/!d'))
```

The '*' subscript concatenates the array elements together, separated by the IFS.
(I have only recently learned this myself, by the way.)