# Assign variable in gnu parallel conditionally

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-parallel

my code is:

```
echo 'url' | parallel "if curl -ss "$url" | grep yes; then vara+="$(echo {})"; else varb+="$(echo {})"; fi"
```

But variables are not being set. If then statement works perfectly eg . `if curl $url | grep yes; then echo done; else echo undone; fi` ---> such thing works but variables are not being set

Can anyone help me find my mistake.

Desired Output: is if if curl url and grep certain word in source then that url will be appended to a variable using += and if word not found then it will be apended in another variable .
Finally after script is over i want to have to variables: vara contains all url list having specific word and varb contains list of urls not having that word in source. that variables are furthet used in scripts

Comment: They're being set, but in different processes. `parallel` doesn't provide the sort of interprocess communication you are looking for.

Comment: Other problems include: quotes don't nest, so `... "if curl -ss "$url" ...` is parsed as a double-quoted string `if curl -ss ` followed by a *completely unquoted* variable reference, then the start of another double-quoted string. Also, everything like `$url` and `$(echo {})` gets interpreted and turned into fixed strings by the shell before they're passed to the `parallel` command as arguments. Put the `set -x` command before this, and you can see how bash interprets this as it runs.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve please? I mean, what is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; Accummulate all results in a single array, **in the calling process**, and sort them out afterwards.

For each URL, output either `SUCCESS:URL` or `FAIL:URL`

Accumulate that into a single array:

```
Results=( $(parallel 'status="FAIL"; curl something && status="SUCCESS"; printf "$status:%s" {}') )
```

which will give `Results` like:

```
SUCCESS:www.ibm.com
SUCCESS:www.google.com
FAIL:www.chocolate-teapots.com
```

Now select/sort the elements using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9764797/2836621) answer.

Agreed that sorting afterwards is not *exactly* what you were looking for, but I assume the reason for wanting to do it in parallel was the latency of `curl` which is still being avoided, and selecting/sorting even thousands of array elements will only take milliseconds.

---

**Explanation**

Your script is setting array elements, but within the new process that **GNU Parallel** starts for each job... and which exits when that job is complete.

---

You could use **GNU Parallel** `parset` like this to fill an array:

```
parset Results 'sleep 3; seq {}' ::: {1..10}
echo "${Results[@]}"
```

And you'd set it up with:

```
env_parallel --install
<<start a new shell>>
```

but that wouldn't be my choice.